# How to execute a (simple) script in iTerm2

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm2

I have the following python script which toggles my keyboard in Karabiner:

```
$ kb_toggle.py
```

It takes about 0.01s to run and toggles my keyboard profile. Is there a way in `iTerm2` to execute a script on a keypress? I've looked at the python scripting examples and all of them look quite overkill (and all of them async, which I don't care about). Basically, I'm just looking to map:

<kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>k</kbd>

It's already on my system path and all that, so I guess how question boils down to: how can I run a basic immediate python (or shell) script in `iTerm2` ?

Comment: You can use `bind` in bash to bind a command to a key combination.

Comment: @Philippe -- thanks, could you please show an example of that (using Cmd too, which usually isn't available in linux)

Comment: `bind '"'$(tput kf2)'":"kb_toggle.py\n"'` to bind `kb_toggle.py` to `F2` I have never try to bind cmd+... with bash/bind. Seems possible https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/300153/387273  in iTerm2